# Getting some UI related issue using Angular.js and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have one issue.I have one navbar in my page .while i am visiting each menu the navbar is shaking .Let me to explain my code below.

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="dashboard">Home</a></li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active" ><a ui-sref=".profile">College Profile</a></li> 
    <li  ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.res')}">
    <a ui-sref="dashboard.res.userrole">Resource Management</a>

    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.deptmanagement')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.deptmanagement.stream" >Department Management</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.user')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.user.usermanagement">User Management</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.plan')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.plan.timetable">Plan Management</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:120px;"  ui-view>
</div>
```

Here my each menu from above is containing some form and CRUD operation.When user is clicking on each menu this bar is slightly shaking side to side.Here i need when user will click on any of the menu it should happen like that means that menu bar will remain constant.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Gonna need more code than that.  Can you set up an example on codepen?

Comment: share your css too with html

Comment: More code is there its too difficult to add all things here.Can you please add one class to prevent this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion as per your statement "When user is clicking on each menu this bar is ***slightly shaking side to side***."

```
you need move your <ul> navbar code to, out of <ui-view>.
```

example

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="dashboard">Home</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active" ><a ui-sref=".profile">College Profile</a></li> 
<li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.res')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.res.userrole">Resource Management</a></li>
<li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.deptmanagement')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.deptmanagement.stream" >Department Management</a></li>
<li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.user')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.user.usermanagement">User Management</a></li>
<li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.plan')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.plan.timetable">Plan Management</a></li>
</ul>

<div ui-view></div>
```

Comment: I am not clear from your answer.Whatever the code i have posted these are only nav bar code.Rest of the code for a page is also there which i have not posted.So the total page with nav bar is rendering inside the `<ui-view>`.

Comment: yes, so your total page code including the navbar code is inside the <ui-view>. there the problem comes, while you move from 1 url to another, every time content of <ui-view> rewrites, that time <ul> navbar also rewrites, thats the reason, you are seeing the slight shaking. so if you move the <ul> navbar code to above the <ui-view> (out of) then, only the page code will inserted into <ui-view> and <ul> navbar code will not be re-rendered (so that you will not see the shaking).

Comment: No,<ul> navbar is not rewriting each time.Inside this page i have also one <ui-view> which contains the respective pages after click on each menu ans those pages doesnot have any ul-navbar but only forms. Finaly this total page is rendering the root <ui-view>.

Comment: in that case, more description/code required as asked by above users in their comment.

Comment: check my post again.all menu pages are inside the given `ui-view`  and also all menu respective pages do not have any <ul> navbar.Those have only forms and lists.